# How to do ssh tunnelling into a private network?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, route

My local machine (A) can access a login server (B) via SSH.
The login server (B) can access a computing server (C) via SSH.

That is, (B) has a public IP. (C) has only a private IP within the private network to which (B) also belongs.

In order to do ssh directly from my local machine (A) to server (C), I followed the method in the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827685/pycharm-configuring-multi-hop-remote-interpreters-via-ssh

I got the below error message:
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: No route to host

It seems my local machine does not know how to route the packets to the server (C).
I think the routing should be done by the server (A).

I spent dozens of hours, but couldn't figure out how.
Any comment is appreciated

thanks!

Comment: Could you give us more details please? To which service you want to connect by the tunnel? Could you share us any command "example"?

Answer (score 0):

I use the ProxyJump feature in openssh for this purpose, maybe is this suitable for you: see https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/advanced-ssh-6-things/

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted! but it outputs the same error message: "channel 0: open failed: connect failed: No route to host"